# using different layers in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to create the layered structure (for eg. like the ones you see in photoshop) in an iPhone app.
Something like an image is being displayed and on top of it (a different layer) are controls like rotate...etc...
If yes, could anyone tell me how its done?
Any suggestion appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this is possible. This is the basic principle of views and subviews. If you want to do such a thing, you should start reading a iPhone development book.

Comment: hey...thanks for the reply :)  by the way, i came across something called CALayer, can this also be used for the layering purpose???

Comment: CA stands for CoreAnimation. So the CALayer's are used for animating stuff. On the iPhone every UIView has a CALayer assigned (on Mac OS X you have to request that first). So the Layer is used to render the view. 

But as long as you don't do some super hyper special animation stuff you don't have to care about the CALayer's.

Comment: hey... i used the concept of subviews in the main view and works perfectly well... The main view controls the rest of the views so whenever i needed to manipulate part of the view, i simply put it in a different subview (layer). Works like a charm! :)) Thanks V1ru8!!!